# How to check if signed url's session is exceeded in Supabase?

Tags: javascript, supabase

I use fetch every 1 second with setInterval to check whether the session of the current signed url has ended, and when ok is not 200, I consider that the session has ended and notify that the session has ended. However, if you use this method, get network error 404 will occur to the user, and too many fetches may be sent, which may result in rejection.
Is there any good way using supabase api to replace this?

```js
setInterval(function() {
   try {
    const response = await fetch(File's signed url);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Request faild');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // file is excessed
    .....
  }
}, 1000);
```